# Rank of matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Let $M$ a matrix over $M(m,k,\mathbb{K})$ and matrix $B$ over $M(m,l,\mathbb{K})$. What is the sufficient condition for $\operatorname{rank}(\lbrack M\mid B \rbrack ) = \operatorname{rank}(M)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Assuming I've understood your notation correctly)

You need each column of $B$ to be a linear combination of columns of $M$.

Comment: $[M|B]$ is augmented matrix?